# Add ASP.NET Window's feature to IIS 7

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, coldfusion

On the final step of configuring the web server connector for ColdFusion 9.0.1 on a Windows 2008 box running IIS 7 I get the following message:

> ASP.NET Window's feature is not installed. They are required to configure the IIS7 connector.

I've looked in the Server Manager Features area but can not find it.

Comment: up-vote for an outstanding question, as always...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you go to manage your server (Windows I am talking about here) you likely added the IIS role. I believe what you need to do from there is "Add Features" to that role. Amongst the other features you should see an option for ASP.NET.

I don't have Win2k8 in front of me, so I cannot verify that, but that is how I remember it. I never got that error, I suspect I always just installed ASP.NET from the get-go.

Comment: I updated our doc to indicate that ASP.NET should be enabled during IIS7 installation.